# Support query by humming using MIDI files

Tags: midi

I read that one can support query by humming by using MIDI files. Can someone please give me an idea on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to IEEE Library: [Query by humming of midi and audio using locality sensitive hashing](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4518093)

Quoting from [Query by Humming of MIDI and Audio Using Locality Sensitive Hashing, audio retrieval examples](http://www.cs.tut.fi/sgn/arg/matti/demos/qbh/)

> We propose a query by humming method based on locality sensitive
>   hashing (LSH). The method constructs an index of melodic fragments by
>   extracting pitch vectors from a database of melodies. In retrieval,
>   the method automatically transcribes a sung query into notes and then
>   extracts pitch vectors similarly to the index construction. For each
>   query pitch vector, the method searches for similar melodic fragments
>   in the database to obtain a list of candidate melodies. This is
>   performed efficiently by using LSH. The candidate melodies are ranked
>   by their distance to the entire query and returned to the user. To
>   retrieve audio signals, we apply an automatic melody transcription
>   method to construct the melody database directly from music
>   recordings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an open source query by humming system which support the midi for building song db: https://github.com/EmilioMolina/QueryBySingingHumming

and see the reference:

[1] Lei Wang, Shen Huang, Sheng Hu, Jiaen Liang, Bo Xu, An Effective and Efficient Method for Query by Humming System Based on Multi-Similarity Measurement Fusion, ICALIP, 2008

[2] Lei Wang, Shen Huang, Sheng Hu, Jiaen Liang, Bo Xu, Improving Searching Speed and Accuracy of Query by Humming System Based on Three Methods: Feature Fusion, Candidates Set Reduction and Multiple Similarity Measurement Rescoring, INTERSPEECH, 2008

[3] http://mirlab.org/dataSet/public/MIR-QBSH-corpus.rar

[4] http://www.esac-data.org/